# C++ Template, learning for the first time, what is wrong with this code?

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning C++ templates for the first time, and have copied this code from "Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ by Michael Goodrich."

I get the error "Line 13: SLinkedList is not a template." I am at a complete loss as to why it is not since I have used "template " everywhere.

```
    // ------------------ DEFINITION FOR NODE ------------------------
template <typename E>
class SNode{

    private:
        E elem;
        SNode<E>* next;


        friend class SLinkedList<E>;

    public:
        SNode(E element = NULL);
        const E getElem() const;
        void setElem(E element);


};

template <typename E>
SNode<E>::SNode(E element){ elem = element;}

template <typename E>
const E SNode<E>::getElem() const
    {return elem;}

template <typename E>
void SNode<E>::setElem(E element)
    {elem = element;}






// -------------------- DEFINITION FOR SINGLY-LINKED LIST --------------
template <typename E>
class SLinkedList
{
    private:
        SNode<E>* head;

    public:
        SLinkedList();
        ~SLinkedList();
        bool isempty() const;
        const E& infront() const;
        void addfront(const E& e);
        void removefront();


};

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::SLinkedList()
    :head(NULL) {}

template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::~SLinkedList()
    {while(!isempty()) removefront();}

template <typename E>
bool SLinkedList<E>::isempty() const
    {return (head == NULL);}

template <typename E>
const E& SLinkedList<E>::infront() const {return head->elem;}

template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::addfront(const E& element) {

    SNode<E>* v = new SNode<E>;
    v->elem = element;
    v->next = head;
    head = v;
}

template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::removefront() {
    SNode<E>* old = head;
    head = old->next;
    delete old;

}

int main()
{


    std::cout<<"Checking SLinkedList ..."<<std::endl<<std::endl;


    SLinkedList<int> intList;
    intList.addfront(13);
    std::cout<<intList.head->next->getElem();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Forward-declare `SLinkedList` before the friend declaration in `SNode`.

Comment: `intList.head->next->getElem();` accesses a private member. `SNode(E element = NULL);` is not a good default construction (`NULL` is a macro "which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant" C99 7.17/3), maybe use `SNode(E element = E());`

Comment: As [Kornel Kisielewicz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/233522/kornel-kisielewicz) described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18178776/420683), `template <typename E>
class SLinkedList;` is the correct forward-declaration here. In this case, you should place it in the global namespace prior to the definition of the class `SNode`. More generally, you should place a forward-declaration in the same namespace and scope as the definition of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
friend class SLinkedList<E>;
```

This can be anything. The compiler doesn't know what it is. But if you tell him before declaring `SNode` that it will be defined later...:

```
template <typename E>
class SLinkedList;
```

... it might work ;)

Comment: +1 Yet: "This can be anything." This couldn't be *anything*. It's clear from the syntax that it's a class template. The problem is that a friend declaration is a *declaration* (i.e. introduces a name), so this would have to declare the class *template* `SLinkedList`. Yet, the compiler cannot know at this point or deduce from this declaration what template parameters this class template shall have. (This is why `template<class T> friend class SLinkedList;` works w/o forward declaration.)

Comment: Adding `template <typename E> class SLinkedList;` to the top of my program worked. It compiled. But on instantiating SLinkedList<int>, I get the error that SNode<int>::elem is a private variable. Isn't SLinkedList as "friend class" aloowed access to private variables

Comment: @ShikharNigam Please give us the whole program and exact error message including the line where it refers to.

Comment: The code is the same as above with the changes made as suggested, i.e., inserted `template <typename E> class SLinkedList;` at the start of my program and fixed the SNode constructor to `SNode<E>::SNode(E elem = E())`. \n
The error I get now are:

error: ‘SNode<int>* SLinkedList<int>::head’ is private
error: ‘SNode<int>* SNode<int>::next’ is private
|115|error: within this context|

Answer (score 2):

You are using `SLinkedList<E>` even before declaring it. Before using it in you class `SNode', please declare it which is known as forward declaration.